# Fastest communication protocol for Azure

Tags: .net, azure

I'm working on a "service" for collecting information from many applications in Azure. Simple idea is that each of these applications will use some "component" (provided by me) for sending audit data to the "service" which will store it in a central DB for reporting and so on.

Assumption is that the client applications will be also in Azure but can be owned/hosted by different companies. Practically each interaction with the client application will send audit to the "service" so there can be a lot of traffic.

I'm new to Azure so will appreciate all tips and suggestions.

Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to skin a cat as always.

You would typically expose a web service (SOAP or REST depending on the capabilities you require, i.e. security) for the application to call, the service would then do whatever work you need it to do  (i.e. write to the database).

You might want to consider using a [service bus queue](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/messaging/) to decouple taking the data from the application and write it to the database and potentially achieve greater throughput (at the cost of latency from application to database)

You could in theory let the application talk to the database directly, but that would typically be considered a bad idea and an abstraction later there (through a service of a kind) would allow you to make changes to the underlying database without impacting the application.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get good overview of what azure supports

http://cloudinteropelements.cloudapp.net/Standards-Based-Messaging-in-Windows-Azure.aspx